# Evaluate vs Save

Tags: labels, save

In my Web-App the user can save data, which is automatically evaluated and some feedback will be provided in the next step.

A user enters some Data, hits a button to save that data and is redirected to another page which displays this data and a symbol right next to it (the result of the evaluation).

The primary use of this form is to save the data to permanently store it and to later compare it with other, similar entries. The secondary use is the instant-evaluation (for example if the entered value is out of the typical bounds) solely on that data-entry.

[image: Example Screen, awesome Paint-Skills]

*Now what to name the button marked with a question-mark?*
Is it `Save`, because the data actually gets saved permanently, and only as Bonus you also get the evaluation?
Is it `Evaluate`, because you get an evaluation instantly, but the data is also saved?

While `Evaluate` seems right to me, in my eyes it doesn't communicate the fact that the data is also saved and can be retrieved later. I fear a user might wonder if their data is really stored and may fear to leave the page because the work they invested by entering the data might be gone when they simply leave. In the Application you always get feedback when you try to leave a page with unsaved content, but this isn't the case here, as all content has been saved.

So again, which is better for the understanding of the user, `Save` or `Evaluate`? Or maybe another possibility I haven't thought of?

Comment: Does it really have to be one single word? What about 'Evaluate and save'? Websites are bigger than 800x600 these days, you can use that space a bit more effectively.

Comment: @JonW While that is a valid point that I hadn't thought about, the site is also responsive and the button has to fit on a smartphone-display. I'll have to get back to the drawing-board and see if it would work out. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You can just add a footnote/info below the input boxes (or near the 'evaluate' button as applicable), which helps the user understand that these values would be saved and can be checked upon later. Something like - "Evaluation also saves your data for later reference".

Comment: Why not just "Save and Continue"?

Comment: It would help to know more about the context, what does a failed evaluation actually mean? What is the reason for keeping saved items where the evaluation has failed?

Answer (score 3):

> The primary use of this form is to save the data to permanently store
>   it and **to later compare it** with other, similar entries.

Referring to your note above - I think **Save & Compare** will be the appropriate label for that button, because:

**Evaluate** is more about Assessing, Judging, Estimating

**Compare** is more about noting the similarity or dissimilarity between

---

## Update

You can also use the **technique of validating the data as the user types** - it's similar to what many websites do these days which will:

- eliminate the confusion of comparing
- users don't have to waste their time by clicking on the back button when data is not unique
- you will need only one button that will be **Save**.

---

Here's a twitter example for the same:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the word 'evaluate'.

What you need is client-side validation, with appropriate error messages, accompanied by simple ajax calls to your server.

In the scenario you describe, it feels like the user is going to enter a cycle of back-and-forth between the two pages, not really knowing what has saved and what has not.

Firstly, disable the save button until valid entries are entered into the fields, or prevent form submission until the fields are valid. [Jquery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) does an excellent, if quirkily-documented job of this.

Use appropriate messaging to let your users correct any errors as efficiently as possible, e.g. 'Value 2 must be less than 9000'

Secondly, you do not need to go to another page to display the evaluation/save message. Ajax to your server and present a nice, subtle 'Saved' message at the top of your screen for a few seconds, once the process has completed.

You will not then need a 'Back' button, which IMHO is confusing because your two screens are otherwise the same.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest informing about both using one compound message on the button.

If it is saving, and then evaluating on the server side:

> **[Save and proceed to Evaluation]**

or:

> **[Save and Evaluate]**

Or, if it's first evaluation and then saving that happens:

> **[Evaluate and Save]**

Or use a supportive text:

> **[Save]**
>
> (Your data will be evaluated before saving.)